# Adblock Warning Removal List for iOS - block 'Please disable Ad-Block'

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, privacy

I use Adblock Warning Removal List for Safari on macOS.

> Adblock Warning Removal List Warning Removal list filter subscription
>   when enabled, blocks these sorts of anti-adblock warnings and
>   obtrusive messages on websites.

Howto use **Adblock Warning Removal List** for iPhone? I don't know how to add custom filter list like in desktop browsers.

I use [Wipr](http://www.giorgiocalderolla.com/wipr.html) app and it's a black box. The "*please disable your Ad blocker*" banners are very annoying. Do I need to switch to an other Ad block app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed.  You can also contact the software developer for assistance with their product.

Answer (score 1):

From the Wipr webpage you‘ve linked to:

> There is no configuration.